# JUNG on Android

Tags: android, jung, graph-visualization

I have been trying to figure out how to use JUNG (http://jung.sourceforge.net/) on Android. As far as I know the Android SDK does not support swing. Is there an Android port of the JUNG renderer or some tool that will convert swing code into the proper UI code for android?

Comment: Since Swing is not available on Android platform, a crazy idea which I don't try will be like using SwingMe to port J2SE->J2ME->Android http://swingme.sourceforge.net/ see its sample helloword here http://swingme.sourceforge.net/helloworld.shtml

Comment: how do you relate javame to android?